# Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. bunnies_array was 0x5CB3CBA

Tags: c++, visual-c++

hello i'm novice at programing and i was playing with classes to get used to it, but i found that when ever i use loop with an array in my class i get this error 
Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. bunnies_array was 0x5CB3CBA.

```
bunny.h   

     #pragma once
        #include <iostream>

        class bunny {
        public:
            int change(int(&bunnies_array)[100]);

        };

bunny.cpp

    #include "bunny.h"

    int bunny::change( int(&array)[100])
    {

        for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            array[i] = 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

main.cpp

    #include "bunny.h"

    int main()
    {
         int bunnies_array[100];

        bunny trail;

        trail.change((&bunnies_array)[100]);
        std::cout << bunnies_array[0];
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
trail.change((&bunnies_array)[100]);
```

to

```
trail.change(bunnies_array);
```

The initial line passes array elements starting from 100th, above the array bounds. I suppose you misunderstood reference to array declaration `int(&bunnies_array)[100]` and mixed it with an address of the array `&bunnies_array`.

Comment: A suggestion: since your change(int[]) function doesn't need to return anything, why not make it void instead of int?

Comment: To elaborate on @S.M.'s response, you need to remember that when you're passing arrays to functions, you're really passing a (constant) pointer that points to the address of the first element of the array itself. Each subsequent element is placed at the size (in bytes) of the object or variable your array stores times its position. Thus, in order to call the function, you have two options:
1) pass the pointer itself, e.g. myFunction(arr);
2) pass the address of the first element of the array, e.g. myFunction(&arr[0]);

Comment: oh, I thought when i pass for example function((&arr)[0]) i'll pass the whole array but it will be passing from the start  hahahaha ,thanks man you really helped me a lot

Comment: Functions are not aware of an array size, that's why you either write the number of iterations directly in the loop condition or pass the size as a parameter and use that instead.